# open custom activity in another app without defining intent-filters

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to open a custom activity (not Main Activity) in another app that developed by someone else and I can't add intent-filters. I wonder if there is a way to achieve this?

Any thought or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: why you can't add intent filters? can you please elaborate on what you need?

Comment: I can't add intent filter because its someone else app!